# How do I remove no-break spaces from a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

So I have a column, incarceration_date, that is actually a text field and I would like to cast it as a date.  Normally no problem, but it seems that every value in this column has a no-break space (&#160) at the end which of course makes the date function error.

I've tried two different approaches to this problem without success.

Attempt 1:

```
trim(both chr(65279) from incarceration_date)::DATE
```

Attempt 2:

```
regexp_replace(incarceration_date, '\s+$', '')::DATE
```

I think the second attempt fails because [[:space:]] doesn't include zero width no-break space.

In this particular instance the fields are all of the same width so I can work around this problem by only passing the first ten characters to the date function.  However, I do have some generic text cleaning functions I use on imported data and I would like them to be able to handle this character.

A sample string looks like this:

```
"06/17/2011 "
```

But I'm not sure that the problem character copies to SO correctly.

I'm using PostgreSQL-9.5.0.

The output of one row of the incarceration_date column output through encode(incarceration_date::bytea, 'hex') is:

```
30362f31372f32303131c2a0
```

All rows end with `c2a0`.

The server encoding is UTF8.

Comment: You could remove anything besides `[0-9/]` from the string

Comment: Can you provide the sample result of `encode(incarceration_date::bytea, 'hex')`? Also provide the encoding of your database (`show server_encoding;`)

Comment: @Abelisto I've added that information to the question.

Comment: 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' is `efbbbf` in UTF8 encoding so you have something else (`c2a0`) at the end of the your field.

Comment: @Abelisto Huh...Thanks. Any idea what?

Comment: The simple googling for "c2a0" shows [Unicode Character 'NO-BREAK SPACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). Good luck.

Comment: PS: `trim(both chr(160) from incarceration_date)::DATE`

Answer (score 1):

As @ThiefMaster stated, you're probably better off removing *anything* other than digits and slashes, just in case you have any other garbage in the field:

```
regexp_replace(incarceration_date, '[^0-9/]', '')::DATE
```

Alternatively, for performance, if you know that the date will always be formatted like `DD/MM/YYYY`, then `just use left(incarceration_date, 10)`, or even `incarceration_date::char(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

I got also the same problem to removing non-breaking spaces.

This will show the non-break characters, look for "C2 A0"

```
encode(convert_to(>>your_field<<, 'UTF-8'), 'hex')
```

I am using this function to remove "C2 A0" characters:

```
regexp_replace(>>your_field<<,'\xa0','')
```